# How to split single cell with multiple values into single

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Please see sample doc:**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yfry2Xf26JVLeoSXpzuzT8HWZhQz4sQK5KJ5clbH-Dg/edit#gid=0

I have 2 columns of data. Col1 = id Col2 = 3 data points, but multiple rows of this data just repeats after itself in a single cell.

```
[id][text1 num1 num1 text2 num2 num3 text3 num3 num3]
```

and I need it to look like:

```
[id][text1][num1][num1]
[id][text2][num2][num2]
[id][text3][num3][num3]
```

I found [this script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60861/google-sheets-split-multi-line-cell-into-new-rows-duplicate-surrounding-row-e) which is able to give me the IDs in each row, but because it splits by " ", it ends up creating 2 columns and gives every value in the array an `[id]`. I also had a separate formula written that was helping me transpose the data so I could force it into 4 columns. Both script and formula are in the linked spreadsheet.

**Possible Solution // Question**

Is there a way to replace every third " " (before every `[text]` value) with another delimiter? Or even split on every 3rd " "?

Stuck here and would really appreciate some ideas or other methods of attack. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to achieve the following situation using Google Apps Script.

  - From

    ```
      [id][text1 num1 num1 text2 num2 num3 text3 num3 num3]
    ```
  - To

    ```
      [id][text1][num1][num1]
      [id][text2][num2][num2]
      [id][text3][num3][num3]
    ```

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your sample Google Spreadsheet. And, please put the custom formula of `=SAMPLE(A3:B5)` to a cell when your sample Spreadsheet is used.

```
const SAMPLE = values => values.reduce((ar, [a, b]) => {
  const temp = b.split(" ");
  while (temp.length > 0) {
    ar.push([a, ...temp.splice(0, 3)]);
  }
  return ar;
}, []);
```

#### Result:

When above script is run for your sample Spreadsheet, the following situation is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: This is absolutely phenomenal. Does exactly what I need and you figured this out so quickly. Will need to study this... thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

For a formula-based approach you can try

```
=query(index(iferror(split(flatten(A3:A5&" "&split( regexreplace(B3:B5, "(\d?[A-Za-z]+)\d*", "¬$1"), "¬")), " ", 0))), "where Col2 <>''", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: This also works exceptionally well! These are some great formulas to store for later, thanks for the response!